# Android Java Accessing Front Flash of Phone

Tags: java, android, xml

Only few phones come with Front Facing LED Flash how can I access it in Java Android. I did a lot of search but found nothing. Phones such as Galaxy J5, J7 and some LG and HTC phone come with front facing LED flash so first I need to find whether if the phone has a  front LED flash and if it have so how to access that.

Will my application be OEM dependent or all front facing cameras has got the same interface???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latest **Camera2** API available, you can check if the front facing camera has flash feature available by using the code shown below

```
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (hasFlashForFrontCamera(cameraManager)) {
            // has flash for front camera
        }

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

boolean hasFlashForFrontCamera(CameraManager cManager) throws CameraAccessException {
    for(final String cameraId : cManager.getCameraIdList()){
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        int cOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if(cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
            return characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

once confirm whether the device front camera has flash, then to **ENABLE** the flash

```
cameraManager.setTorchMode(frontCameraId, true);
```

to **DISABLE** the FLASH

```
cameraManager.setTorchMode(frontCameraId, false);
```

you can use the above code snippet

Comment: @HasifSeyed thanks for the Help it works like Charm thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.hardware.camera.flash
```

The app uses the flash feature that the device's camera supports.

By using this feature, an app implies that it also uses the `android.hardware.camera` feature, unless this parent feature is declared with `android:required="false"`.

**To use the device's front-facing camera.**

```
 android.hardware.camera.front
```

By using this feature, an app implies that it also uses the `android.hardware.camera` feature, unless this parent feature is declared with `android:required="false"`.

See this Documentation -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html